# Official name(s) for a certain type of p-group

Tags: group-theory, terminology, finite-groups

I'm implementing a class of groups into Sage (sagemath.org), a computer algebra system, and I'm wondering if it has any official names. I found it in Gorenstein's "Finite Groups." It is there called $M_m(p)$, and has the presentation $\langle x, y \shortmid x^{p^{m-1}} = y^p = 1, x^y = x^{1+p^{m-2}} \rangle$. The family is notable because they are the only nonabelian p-groups (for odd p) that have maximal cyclic subgroups. I'm looking for any common names for this family of groups, perhaps even what Gorenstein meant by his $M_m(p)$ notation.

Comment: Well, for one thing they are split metacyclic groups...

Comment: I believe Tim Dokchitser decided to call them OMC (other maximal cyclic), though this might be because of something I wrote which was only a convenience to me. I assumed M stands for maximal. I suggest that it does not stand for modular. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48434/names-of-finite-groups